# Git SHA in CodeBuild?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

How can I get the Git SHA of a commit from a CodeBuild build when the source code is managed by CodeCommit?

Like any other Git repository, each CodeCommit commit gets a unique Git SHA. When CodeBuild executes a `buildspec.yml` the Git SHA can be read from the [CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html) environment variable.

However, I would like to know the Git SHA from "outside" of CodeBuild, i.e. in a Lambda function that is triggered by CodeBuild events of ["detail-type": "CodeBuild Build State Change"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-build-notifications.html#sample-build-notifications-ref). Unfortunately, if you read the documentation you will find that the Git SHA is not part of the event data. I have also tried calling the [CodeBuild.batchGetBuilds()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CodeBuild.html#batchGetBuilds-property) function (since I know the build id from the CodeBuild event), regrettably there is no Git SHA in that response either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for using AWS CodeBuild. For builds set with git based sources, the Git SHA can be found in resolvedSourceVersion field in CodeBuild.batchGetBuilds() output, or the CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION environment variable during the build. The resolvedSourceVersion in the API output is only available after the DOWNLOAD_SOURCE phase. CodeBuild released this change to [AWS JavaScript SDK in version 2.328.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#23280) a week ago.

You can post this on the AWS forum so we can better troubleshoot the issue for you.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, that was timely.

Comment: Hi, the CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION is for the first/primary source, the git commit ids for other sources appears to not be available from the build environment?